# Leaving a BinaryReader object un-disposed in order to keep Request.InputStream alive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inputstream

I have a couple methods to handle the saving of an image using Request.InputStream. I have two extensions that share the HttpContext. In one of my methods, I'm using a BinaryReader to read in the contents and do the processing. However, naturally, when disposing the BinaryReader, it closes off the InputStream property on Request. My SECOND method uses the same input stream to create a thumbnail.

Bascially, I need a way to keep the Request.InputStream property alive after disposing the reader in the first method. Is this possible? Here are my two methods. SaveImageStream() is called first, then GenerateThumbnail().

```
public static void SaveImageStream(this HttpContextBase ctx, string filename)
{
    var config = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConfig>();

    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ctx.Request.InputStream))
    {
        var bandImagesPath = config.GetSetting<string>("BandImagePath");
        var path = Path.Combine(ctx.Server.MapPath(bandImagesPath), filename);

        byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)ctx.Request.InputStream.Length);

        using (var outputStream = System.IO.File.Create(path, 2048))
        {
            const int chunkSize = 2 * 1024; // 2KB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead;
            ctx.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = ctx.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void GenerateThumbnail(this HttpContextBase ctx, string filename)
{
    var config = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConfig>();

    int size = config.GetSetting<int>("ThumbSize");
    var thumbPath = Path.Combine(ctx.Server.MapPath(config.GetSetting<string>("ThumbPath")), filename);

    var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ctx.Request.InputStream);
    var thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(size, size, null, IntPtr.Zero);

    thumb.Save(thumbPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling one method from another, you can do everything within the `using` statement.  I'm also wondering about this line:

```
byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)ctx.Request.InputStream.Length);
```

You aren't using the `file` variable anywhere, which has the entire request stream resident in memory.  If you aren't careful this would be an avenue for a Denial of Service attack.  But on to the solution...

Change the thumbnail method to look like this:

```
public static void SaveImageStream(this HttpContextBase ctx, string filename)
{
    var config = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConfig>();

    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ctx.Request.InputStream))
    {
        var bandImagesPath = config.GetSetting<string>("BandImagePath");
        var path = Path.Combine(ctx.Server.MapPath(bandImagesPath), filename);

        using (var outputStream = System.IO.File.Create(path, 2048))
        {
            const int chunkSize = 2 * 1024; // 2KB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead;
            ctx.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = ctx.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }

        ctx.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        ctx.GenerateThumbnail(filename);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a MemoryStream around that `file` attribute, and send that to the `GenerateThumbnail` extension method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "decorator" pattern to wrap the InputStream. Have a look at the end of this post for an example:

http://ydie22.blogspot.com/2008/02/about-idisposable-close-streams-and.html

Comment: There is also a fully implemented decorator in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) - `NonClosingStreamWrapper` or similar.